# Dynamic Programming Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

I was learning dynamic programming's application to the Fibonacci Sequence and had a question. Here is the code for reference:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FibonacciNumbersB {

    static BigInteger[] dp = new BigInteger[10000];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays.fill(dp, BigInteger.ZERO);
        dp[0] = BigInteger.ONE;
        dp[1] = BigInteger.ONE;

        for(int i = 4; i < 9999; i++)
            System.out.println(fibRecurse(i).toString());
    }

    public static BigInteger fibRecurse(int N) {
        for(int i = 2; i < N; i++) {
            // For numerous calls to this function, this will save as it goes
            if(dp[i].equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
                dp[i] = dp[i - 1].add(dp[i - 2]);
        }

        return dp[N - 1];
    }
}
```

I have a statement check if `dp[i]` equals `0` in the `fibRecurse` method (although `fibRecurse` isn't recursive).

Is it more efficient to check if `dp[i]` has been calculated already or to just let `dp[i]` equal to the sum of the previous two elements?

Comment: Is it more effective to even check for null or recalculate dp[i]? @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Benchmark your code. But this is not a recursive algorithm, and your memoization isn't going to help.

Comment: Maybe i don't understand your question, but checking the value first would be more efficient rather than always recalculating - for large inputs at least. Isn't that the whole point of dynamic programming?

Comment: @Chris Oh I see. Thanks for your reply - that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch How would I implement this recursively? I tried for about an hour and got nowhere.

Comment: @NathanHughes Oh, I see it now. Dynamic programming would be to use dp[i] = dp[i - 1] + dp[i - 2]. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: no problem. dynamic programming is pretty similar to some other "algorithm types" out there. I think of it kind of like divide and conquer, but you save the "sub-problems" to a solution with the intent of possibly reusing them. hope that helps a bit

Comment: @Chris right on, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer a `Map<Integer, BigInteger>` over using a fixed `BigInteger[]` when performing this *memoization*. Note that your current approach is **not** *recursive*. The `Map` might be declared and initialized like

```
static Map<Integer, BigInteger> memo = new HashMap<>();
static {
    memo.put(0, BigInteger.ONE);
    memo.put(1, BigInteger.ONE);
}
```

Then check if the current `n` is present in the `memo` (if it is, return it) - otherwise, computer and store it. Like,

```
public static BigInteger fibRecurse(int n) {
    if (memo.containsKey(n)) {
        return memo.get(n);
    }
    BigInteger v = fibRecurse(n - 1).add(fibRecurse(n - 2));
    memo.put(n, v);
    return v;
}
```

A version without *memoization* would simply omit `memo` like

```
public static BigInteger fibRecurseSlow(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) return BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger v = fibRecurse(n - 1).add(fibRecurse(n - 2));
    return v;
}
```

I think you can *infer* from the method names I've chosen which is slower.

Comment: Perfect, it makes sense. I always thought using a Map<A, B> wouldn't be O(1) lookup.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FibonacciNumbersB {

    static BigInteger[] dp = new BigInteger[10000];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dp[0] = BigInteger.ONE;
        dp[1] = BigInteger.ONE;
        int N = 9999;
         fibRecurse(N);
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            System.out.println(dp[i].toString()) ;
    }

    public static void fibRecurse(int N) {
        for(int i = 2; i < N; i++) {

                dp[i] = dp[i - 1].add(dp[i - 2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this not slower than the method above?

Comment: time complexity is the same as  @Elliott Frisch   answer which is  O(n)

Comment: But for numerous calls you have to repeat the calculation whereas @Elliot Frisch does not have to.

Comment: after the function fibRecurse(N) , i have caculate all from 1th  to  Nth and save them into array.

Comment: Will you not still be calculating the sum over and over again?

Comment: i  just  call  the  calculate  function  once

Comment: If you were to do it again, then this would be less efficient

Answer (score 0):

The code that is for finding fibonacci sequence can be write easily.Let's consider recursive code for finding fibonacci number set.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class fac{
  public static void main(String a[]){

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Your number :");
    int n=sc.nextInt();

    System.out.print(fibonacci(n));
}   

public static int fibonacci(int x){
    if(x<2){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return (fibonacci(x-1)+fibonacci(x-2));
    }
}
```

}

In this stage, there are many same subproblems are calculating  again and again.So in this case, time complexity goes to height for large input. Because of that reason , dynamic programming technique was came ...In dynamic programming ,an extra table('lookUp' table) is maintained for storing previous calculated subproblems' values. before calculating next subproblems' value, check whether availability of the answer for the particular subproblem in created table('lookUp' table).If it is in the 'lookUp table', get the answer for particular subproblem. If it is not in the 'lookUp ' table, calculate value of the particular problem and store the 'lookUp ' table. That is the meaning of the dynamic programming technique.There are two ways for performing this technique.

1.Memoization -
            memoization is the technique that calculating values of subproblems Top- Down manner.Let's consider the code of fibonacci sequence.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 class fab{
   public static void main(String a[]){

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Your number :");
    int n=sc.nextInt();

    int[] lookUp=new int[n];        
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        lookUp[i]=-1;
    }
    fibonachi(n);   
}
public static void fibonachi(int x){
    if(lookUp[x]==-1){
        if(x<=1){
            lookUp[x]=x;
        }
        else{
            lookUp[x]=fibonachi(x-1)+fibonachi(x-2);
        }
    }
    System.out.print(lookUp[x]);
}
```

}

2.Tabulation - This calculation goes to Bottom to Top manner.At first consider the base case and perform . Then perform the next steps using previous cases.Les's consider fibonacci sequence code with tabulation technique.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class fac{
  public static void main(String a[]){

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Your number :");
    int n=sc.nextInt();

    int[] lookUp=new int[n];        
    int i;

    lookUp[0]=1; // store base case values in the 'lookUp' table
    lookUp[1]=1;

    for(i=2;i<n;i++){
        lookUp[i]=lookUp[i-1]+lookUp[i-2];
    }
    System.out.print(lookUp[n-1]);
  }
```

}

In this case , base case values are stored at first.then calculates next values using previous ones..In tabulation all the values must be calculated because new value calculated using previous vlues..so memoization is better than tabulation.That's all. I hope, you could get idea.Thank you!